# Update all rows except identity column in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a form in Access linking to a SQL Server table. This table has a UID. After I create a new record in Access, it tries to update the table (including the UID) and gives me the error:

> Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'TableName' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column.

Now, I understand why this error is occurring but am not sure how to get around it. I can't change IDENTITY_INSERT, and the UID column in Access links the form to a subform, so I do need to include it in the form. **How do I exclude only the UID column from the ODBC update?** I know I can use a macro to explicitly define columns to update, but there must be an easier way. Is there a function like `Me!UIDTextbox.Undo` I can run in the `Before Update` event?

Some more detail:
There's no VBA module or query in Access. It's a standard SQL server table and the Access form updates the table on record change (the default for Access). The table is linked with the standard ODBC Database connection, with the UID as primary key.

Comment: The ODBC driver doesn't update the key, so either something else is going on, or you didn't specify the ID when linking the table (but then you normally can't update at all).

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to Access? "IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column" sounds a lot like SQL Server. Access gives a very different Error message when inserting into an AutoNumber column and doesn't use the term "IDENTITY_INSERT"

Comment: Ah, I get it now. You are connecting to SQL Server via Access (the ODBC is pointing to SQL Server) What does your insert statement look like?

Comment: @Gustav The UID column is specified as the Access table ID.

Comment: @Brad The insert statement is the default in Access. As stated in the question, I don't have any VBA or special requirements. I connected the data source, created a form, and use the default Access fields to update the table.

Comment: It sounds like you are supplying a value, probably inadvertently. When you get this error is it upon saving the parent form, saving the parent/subform combo, entering the subform?

Comment: You use the term "update" but refer to creating a new record. Are you doing an update (changing an existing record) or an insert (a complete new record)?

Comment: @Brad It happens when I save the parent/subform combo, specifically when I try to save the subform.

Comment: @user3728595 I get this error when I do either.

Comment: @jjjjjjjjjjj can you post how your parent/child form is set up? i.e. how do oyu make the connection between the two? If you remove the subform are you able to save the parent? Can you then save a child record? Just as a test, can your parent/child records be saved using tables instead of forms?

Comment: @Brad I deleted the tables from Access, relinked them with a different primary key, and the error is gone. It now writes to the SQL Server table as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a global problem with using Identity columns as Primary Keys in Access.

Patch idea and possible workarounds at
[Problem with identity fields in MS-Access](http://jagbarcelo.blogspot.ca/2006/06/problems-with-identity-fields-in-ms.html)

Comment: Looks like I may in fact have to code the update. I'll give this a try.